# Creating a VPN connection using DotRas - making sure credentials are remembered

Tags: c#, ras, dotras

I am using [DotRas](http://dotras.codeplex.com/) to create a VPN connection. This is working fairly well (preshared key, credentials and such).

The only thing I am having a real difficulty with is making sure the credentials actually **persist**. See the following image. I cannot seem to find a way to make sure that checkbox is actually checked. I have tried everything I could remember.

Having this unchecked renders the saved credentials virtually nonexistent as I am asked to enter username/password upon connection. Yet if I go back to edit this info, the credentials are still there!

If I click on the checkbox manually and do a `Save`, everything works as expected. Any ideas? How can I make sure `Remember my sign-in info` is checked (programmatically)?

[image: This is how it appears on my Windows 10]

Comment: im looking for same answer

Answer (score 0):

I found that if I update the credentials, E.g:

```
VpnEntry.UpdateCredentials(new System.Net.NetworkCredential(Environment.UserName, string.Empty, Environment.UserDomainName));
```

then, at least on Windown 7, the connection will appear with "Save this username and password..." option checked.
Unfortunatelly I can't get it working on Windows 10.

I would look into pinvoking the API's yourself. At least that's what I'm going to do. Will post back with progress.

Rasapi32.dll :: RasSetCredentials - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa377811(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
VpnEntry.Options.CacheCredentials = true;
```

On my Windows 10 professional works.